# Connecting to AppSync GraphQL directly from React App?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm currently implementing an application using AWS Amplify and the tutorial basically is telling me to have the React App hit the AppSync GraphQL endpoints directly.

I'm not quite sure if this is safe since if I'm using API_KEY for example to authenticate, then I would need to have this key embedded inside the react app.

I feel like I should implement a lambda go-between but it's just bizarre that the Amplify tutorial doesn't mention ANYTHING about this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll do something like this [example](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/#simple-query) on the front-end:

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import * as queries from './graphql/queries';
import { GraphQLQuery } from '@aws-amplify/api';
import { ListTodosQuery, GetTodoQuery } from './API';

// Simple query
const allTodos = await API.graphql<GraphQLQuery<ListTodosQuery>>(
  { query: queries.listTodos }
);
console.log(allTodos); // result: { "data": { "listTodos": { "items": [/* ..... */] } } }

// Fetch a single record by its identifier
const oneTodo = await API.graphql<GraphQLQuery<GetTodoQuery>>({
  query: queries.getTodo,
  variables: { id: 'some id' }
});
```

You do not need to deploy Lambda resources when using graphql with aws amplify.